# Loop through NSFetchRequest result

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am quite new to Core Data, and actually Objective-C as a whole, so I hope I am phrasing this correctly, I have been able to store and retrieve data using Core Data, but I am struggling to loop through a result set,

```
// read the data
NSFetchRequest *req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[req setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Card" inManagedObjectContext:app.managedObjectContext]];
//[req setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cardID == %@", @"1"]];
NSArray *crd = [[app.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:req error:nil] lastObject];

for(Card *card in crd){
    NSLog(@"%@",card.backImageURL);
}
```

I keep getting this error though when I try to run the app,

```
2012-10-16 11:37:29.407 Core test[925:17903] -[Card countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x962f5c0
2012-10-16 11:37:29.408 Core test[925:17903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Card countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x962f5c0'
```

I am sure it is something extremely simple but for some reason I can't seem to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
NSArray *crd = [[app.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:req error:nil] lastObject];
```

it should be

```
NSArray *crd = [app.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:req error:nil];
```

If you are getting error, then you should use that error parameter -

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *crd = [app.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];
if(error){
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Oh wow... I didn't even notice the `lastObject`! -_- Thanks man, that did the trick!